# Does the distance between the slits, in the double slit experiment, affect the pattern displayed?

Tags: visible-light, interference

Does the distance between the slits affect the pattern displayed?

I want a pattern where light parts and dark parts are equal, and I don't want the light parts to be bigger than dark parts.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Physics SE. What do you think? What research have you done to answer this question for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The distance between the fringes is inversely proportional to the separation of the slits.

> I want a pattern where light parts and dark parts are equal, and I don't want the light parts to be bigger than dark parts.

Unfortunately, one cannot always get what one wants.

The fringes from a two slit arrangement are not sharp and so such a diagram may be misleading.

[image]

The theoretical intensity pattern depends on the separation of the slits and the width of the slits as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

Photographing the interference pattern is very difficult due to the range of light intensities involved.
The photographs above have been overexposed in the centre region (high intensity) so that the outer regions (low intensity) are visible.